# Rails Formats DateTime.now one way and DateTime.yesterday another - how do I get date in the past formatted like DateTime.now?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have 2 lines of code that attempt to place start and end date times in a JavaScript.  `new Date('<%= DateTime.now.beginning_of_day.to_s %>')` is an example.  The `DateTime.now.beginning_of_day` returns the string `2012-08-13T00:00:00-04:00` which JavaScript translates into 8/13/2012 00:00.  Perfect.  However, `DateTime.yesterday.beginning_of_day.to_s` returns '2012-08-11 20:00:00-04:00' which JavaScript translates into 8/11/2012 20:00.  I don't want 8pm the day before yesterday.  I want midnight yesterday.  I've tried `Date.yesterday`, `.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")`, `.utc` and a myriad of other permutations.  What do I have to do to get a date in the past that is formatted in the same manner as `DateTime.now`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime.now.yesterday.beginning_of_day
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Time.zone

then some hacky to_date back to_time make sure it is zero'd out at midnight

```
new Date('<%= Time.zone.now.to_date.to_time.to_s %>')

new Date('<%= (Time.zone.now - 1.day).to_date.to_time.to_s %>')
```

you should be able to use `Time.zone.now.yesterday.to_date.to_time.to_s` instead of - 1.day